Schedule a task with environment variable configured interval
Using the @Scheduled annotation, I'm able to configure a method to run on a schedule, as follows
@Component
public class DemoScheduledTask {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void runEveryFiveSeconds(){
        System.out.println("Running...");
    }
}


I can also load an environment variable into a java variable using @Value, and it will load properly
@Component
public class DemoScheduledTask {
    @Value("${DEMO_TEST_VAR}")
    int val;

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void runEveryFiveSeconds(){
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}

I'm also able to use a cron expression from the environment by using @Scheduled(cron = "${DEMO_ENV_VAR}" and setting DEMO_ENV_VARto something like*/5 * * * * *`, which results in the same "every 5 seconds logic.
My goal is to set up a scheduled task with a fixedPeriod based on an env var.  I can't use @Scheduled(fixedRate = val) because the argument to fixedRate needs to be a constant expression, and I can't use @Scheduled(fixedRate = "${DEMO_TEST_VAR}") because it needs to be a long, not a String.
Is it possible to pass a variable into fixedRate like this?

please pay attention to javadoc: String fixedRateString: This attribute variant supports Spring-style "${...}" placeholders as well as SpEL expressions.
